# How can I "test data" coming in to a Pi from an UART device connected via TTL-to-USB

Tags: usb, serial, uart

I've got a [Waveshare PN532](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/PN532_NFC_HAT) RFID reader/writer. I want to use it with a Pi 4B, but since it is already using a HAT with no free GPIO, I want to use it in UART mode, but not connecting to the GPIO pins 8 and 10, but rather using a TTL-to-USB adapter. Now I want to follow the first step in the wiki, "Quick testing", which is explaining this for a windows PC and "Serial assistant software". It says the connection should be baud rate 115200 and 8N1. The instruction then is:

> Select correct serial port and open.
>
> Send data below to wake up FN532 module：
>
> `55 55 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 03 FD D4 14 01 17 00`
>
> ...
>
> The response from PN532 module should be：
>
> `00 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 02 FE D5 15 16 00`

How do I do this on the Pi (Raspbian Buster)? I guess I must somehow send these bytes to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and poll the response.

---

Here is an attempt:

- terminal 1: `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 >out.bin`
- terminal 2: `echo -en '\x55\x55\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x03\xFD\xD4\x14\x01\x17\x00' > /dev/ttyUSB0`

But how do I stop cat? If I ctrl-C it, the contents of `out.bin` is empty. If I use use `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`, I can see a response of five unprintable characters; my idea was to `hexdump -C -n out.bin`, but apparently I need to flush and quit cat, or can I pipe it into a "live" hex view without it waiting for linefeed or flush?

[image: photo of ttl-to-usb adapter sitting between Pi and RFID board]

Comment: Not really Pi specific.  Perhaps use `echo` with the `-e` option to send the bytes.

Comment: @joan Can you please advise how to send bytes to ttyUSB0 via echo, and how to hex dump response from ttyUSB0, choosing the given baud rate etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure the device

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo
```

To wait for the next fifteen bytes to arrive

```
$ hexdump -C -n 15 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To send bytes (from a second terminal)

```
$ echo -en '\x55\x55\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x03\xFD\xD4\x14\x01\x17\x00' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The hexdump terminal then should print

```
00000000  00 00 ff 00 ff 00 00 00  ff 02 fe d5 15 16 00     |...............|
0000000f
```